# How place text + input in 2 colums with a vertical align middle

Tags: css, sass

I have a question, it's possible to align like in the example 2 elements with boostrap ?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9UuK.jpg)

Thank by advance !

Anka

Comment: this is just css related, why do you use the angular tag?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Because my project use Angular 4. I can delete the tag if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,
Just Use `display: inline-block` for the text tag, so your final code will look like this:

```
 .text{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```